# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/sprint' by 1 commit

Tags: git, push, gerrit

I get this message from git pull AFTER I've pushed the code to GERRIT (after code reviewing in GERRIT I submit from GERRIT to remote)!

Since I'm using GERRIT - after I "git push" the code to GERRIT and finally submit it to remote through GERRIT, my local git instance seems to think I still have changes I still need to push my changes! 
So I'm forced to do a "git reset HEAD^" to go back 1 commit every time! I'm not losing anything since I've pushed the code to remote using GERRIT at this point but it is very frusrating I have to do this after every git push>Gerrit push to remote!

IS there any suggestion as to how I can get around this?

PS : There have already been some questions about this before. I couldnt find a solution to my scenario via the GERRIT though!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to do hard reset (I prefer `git reset --hard origin master` BTW.) then simply create a new branch prior to committing. After you pushed it, you can throw that branch away.

P.S. you might be interested in trying [git-review](https://m.mediawiki.org/wiki/Gerrit/git-review)

Comment: I checked some of the queries in SE. Oddly- I noticed something this time around: After I get this message (ahead of 1 commit after pushing to gerrit) - Instead of **git pull** - I tried **git fetch**, the problem suddenly seemed to go away. However, after running **git fetch**, my branch showed me as a few hundred commits behind, but NOW doing a **git pull** brought me up-to-date with origin.  I thought **git pull=git fetch and git merge**. I'm not sure i quite understand WHY git fetch approach worked (And I didnt understand,seprately, why git merge did not update my master)

Comment: Didn't seem to get any response....does anyone know what the reason could be behind this?

Comment: Yes, pull = fetch + rebase/merge. Not sure, what happened to you. It brings only the current branch forward. But still, your commit won't just be thrown away by pulling. As said, either do `git reset --HARD`, which is totally okay, because all changes are stored in Gerrit, or use branches. That's it.